# Export dynamic webpage to pdf or excel?

Tags: html, database, jsp, pdf, export

I have a dynamic webpage written in JSP and servlet program where I enter data which gets stored in a database. The data stored is displayed as a table on another webpage on button click. I want my users to download the data on the page which displays the values, either as a PDF or as an excel page. How do I do it?

Comment: try this https://code.google.com/p/jspdf/

Comment: Q1: Do you want to generate the PDF on the server or from within the browser? Note that jspdf is Javascript. Q2: Do you have PHP available on your server? Q3: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to Try a plugin for Firefox

https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-uS/firefox/addon/web2pdf-converter/

Or have the data exported as CSV or PDF via PHP - this can then prompt user to save.

[How to convert MySQL data from page into PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723463/how-to-convert-mysql-data-from-page-into-pdf)

[PHP code to convert a MySQL query to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv)

Comment: I am aware of the plugin but I want to add a button to my webpage.

Comment: Ah... I see. You want to download it? Or do you want your users to download it?

Comment: I want to add a button for the user that will export the displayed table into a PDF or excel file